# Django: checking is_null in values() queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this queryset:

```
output = self.filter(parent=task, user=user).values(
    'label', 'minutes_allotted', 'days_to_complete', 'pk', number_of_children=Count('children')
)
```

It does the job. But I'm really only using it to check if an object has children (I don't really care about how many it has). Is there a way to use `isnull` here?

I've tried:

```
output = self.filter(parent=task, user=user).values(
    'label', 'minutes_allotted', 'days_to_complete', 'pk', 'children__isnull'
)
```

and:

```
output = self.filter(parent=task, user=user).values(
    'label', 'minutes_allotted', 'days_to_complete', 'pk', is_not_parent='children_isnull'
)
```

but neither were correct.

Comment: You want to annotate this to value not just filter by it right?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about annotate. I guess that is the better option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
annotate(\
    has_children=ExpressionWrapper(Q(children__isnull=False), \
output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

Comment: Marking as the solution as it seems like this is the best way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what your model-relations are, but you can filter through relationships like so:

`Grandparent.objects.filter(parents__children__isnull=True)`

This finds all grandparents that do not have any grandchildren.
Depending on the relationships between your grandparents, parents, and children, you may need to add `.distinct()` to your queryset to avoid duplicates.